# Limit civ5 AI player unit count?

Tags: civilization-5

Is it possible to limit total number of units for AI player so they don't clutter the whole  map with unit spamming? This also keeps AI from bankrupting.

Comment: This is theoretically possible but would require far more modding knowledge than I have. There is a hard cap on the number of units a civ can field, based on its number of cities and units. You would need to find a way to create a mod that lowers that value.

Comment: The easiest way to keep the AI from bankrupting is playing on higher difficulties.  Their increased income will keep them (and you if you trade correctly) very well in the black.

Answer (score 1):

At first I misunderstood the question,

You cannot limit the AI unit count in a traditional way. You can however reduce the difficulty of the game, which does affect the unit count.

Other then that,
http://forums.civfanatics.com/showthread.php?t=486324
Mods like these can make you start with a current number of units, get free units at certain times and its also possible to limit units with mods.